# Regex match only one character without anything else

Tags: regex

I'd like to create a regex that catches **every single capital letter** of the text below in the range `[A-G]` **without** the `space` or `\n` character that follows it and also without any character that precedes it. I'd like to catch only what is marked as code in the example text. I've tried it with `[A-G][^\w]` but that is still matches the following spaces or \n as well.

**Example text:**

Capo 1st fret

[Verse]

`C` `G` Am

If I had to live my life without you near me

Em `F` `C`

The days would all be empty

Dm `G`

The nights would seem so long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two common options for not including the non-word characters before or after the match.

1.) [Word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

```
\b[A-G]\b
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/V6t7Es/1)

---

2.) [Lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
(?<!\w)[A-G](?!\w)
```

[Another demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/V6t7Es/2)

---

The lookbehind is least supported within the different regex flavors.